# Configure java 64bit for tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have a webapp using tomcat, this webserver was deployment on Solaris sparce 32, 64 bit.
Normally using JAVA_HOME /u01/app/jdk1.7.0_80 in tomcat. 
How can I can using this /u01/app/jdk1.7.0_80/bin/sparcv9 to JAVA_HOME to using java 64 bit for tomcat. I need this configure because I want to increase Java Heap memory!
Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Wouldn't JAVA_HOME env variabale set to `/u01/app/jdk1.7.0_80` work?

Comment: this work but it was java 32 bit, i need set to 64Bit